# On click on the arrow the flags animated shifted one position to the left or right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new in JS an jQuery. I need some help. I have next task. There are 6 flags on my site with left arrow on the left and right arrow on the right. When you click on the arrow flags animated shifted one position to the left or right. By moving the flags to the left to the right leaves a copy of the leftmost flag and vice versa.

Here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".arrow.left").click(function() {
    var position1 = $("#it").position();
    $("#en").animate(position1);
  });
});
```

```css
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 135px;
  left: 150px;
}
.slider > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
.slides {
  width: 550px;
  height: 53px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 70%;
}
.arrow {
  width: 16px;
  height: 15px;
  background: url(pictures/arrowsSprite.png) no-repeat;
}
.arrow.left {
  background-position: -16px 0;
}
.left:hover {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
.arrow.right {
  background-position: -32px 0;
}
.right:hover {
  background-position: -48px 0
}
.slides > div span {
  min-width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 25px;
  left: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
#de,
#es,
#it,
#en,
#fr,
#nl {
  position: absolute;
  color: #0094d9;
}
#de {
  top: 10px;
}
#es {
  top: 2px;
  left: 90px;
}
#it {
  left: 180px;
}
#en {
  left: 280px;
}
#fr {
  top: 2px;
  left: 373px;
}
#nl {
  top: 10px;
  left: 463px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="arrow left"></div>
  <div class="slides">
    <div id="de">
      <a href="">
        <img src="pictures/Flags/Germany.png" alt="Немецкий"><span>Немецкий</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="es">
      <a href="">
        <img src="pictures/Flags/Spain.png" alt="Испанский"><span>Испанский</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="it">
      <a href="">
        <img src="pictures/Flags/Italy.png" alt="Итальянский"><span>Итальянский</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="en">
      <a href="">
        <img src="pictures/Flags/UK.png" alt="Английский"><span>Английский</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="fr">
      <a href="">
        <img src="pictures/Flags/France.png" alt="Французский"><span>Французский</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="nl">
      <a href="">
        <img src="pictures/Flags/Netherlans.png" alt="Голландский"><span>Голландский</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow right"></div>
</div>
```

I understand, that for one changing position of one flag to another (for example "`#en`" to the position of "`#it`") I can do next: `

But I can't understand, how the position of "`#en`" can be change after next click to the position of "`#es`"? Then to the position of "`#de`" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? (Press "Run code snippet" at the bottom)

```js
var countryHtml = [
  '<a href=""><img src="pictures/Flags/Germany.png" alt="Немецкий"><span>1Немецкий</span></a>',
  '<a href=""><img src="pictures/Flags/Spain.png" alt="Испанский"><span>2Испанский</span></a>',
  '<a href=""><img src="pictures/Flags/Italy.png" alt="Итальянский"><span>3Итальянский</span></a>',
  '<a href=""><img src="pictures/Flags/UK.png" alt="Английский"><span>4Английский</span></a>',
  '<a href=""><img src="pictures/Flags/France.png" alt="Французский"><span>5Французский</span></a>',
  '<a href=""><img src="pictures/Flags/Netherlans.png" alt="Голландский"><span>6Голландский</span></a>'
];

var offset = -1;

var redrawCountries = function (dir) {
  //offset is current country at the #pos0
  offset += dir;
  
  //Moves #pos(i) to the opposite direction of dir (if dir is 1 or "left",
  //it will be moved to the right and then animated back to it's original position.
  //This function will also set the correct country to the div
  var moveElem = function (i) {
    //Get the country (i+offset) and if it is lower than 0, make it zero, if it is
    //higher than 5, make it 5.
    //As offset indicates the country that is supposed to be at #pos0 at the end
    //of the animation and passing in i requests that you animate #pos(i), the
    //country that is supposed to end up in #pos(i) is (i+offset). So at #pos0
    //countryHtml[offset] is supposed to be used. at #pos1, countryHtml[1+offset]
    //and so on.
    var countryIndex = Math.min(Math.max(i+offset, 0), countryHtml.length-1);
    
    //Get the jQuery object of the current element
    var currElem = $("#pos"+i);
    
    //Finishes animation, the important part about finish, is it acts as if the
    //animation completed, so it doesn't stop halfway, but jumps to the end position
    currElem.finish();
    
    //Set the correct html for the current element
    currElem.html(countryHtml[countryIndex]);
    
    //Get the position of the element opposite the current direction (so left element if
    //the right arrow is pressed and vice versa)
    var fromPos = $("#pos"+(i+dir)).position();
    
    //Get the current position to move the element to
    var toPos = currElem.position();
    
    //Set the current element's position to the fromPosition
    currElem.css({ left: fromPos.left, top:  fromPos.top });
    
    //Animate it to the toPosition
    currElem.animate(toPos);
  };
  
  //If it's animated to the left
  if (dir === 1) {
    
    //Iterate from left to right, so that the element the current one relies on (the
    //element to the right of the current one) has not been moved yet
    for (var i = 0;i < 5;i++) {
      moveElem(i);
    }
    
    //Set the element which was not iterated through
    $("#pos5").html(countryHtml[Math.min(Math.max(5+offset, 0), countryHtml.length-1)]);
    
  } else if (dir === -1) { //Animated to the right
    
    //Iterate the other way for the same reason
    for (var i = 5;i > 0;i--) {
      moveElem(i);
    }
    
    //Set the element which was not iterated through
    $("#pos0").html(countryHtml[Math.min(Math.max(offset, 0), countryHtml.length-1)]);
  }
};

$(".arrow.left").click(function() {
  redrawCountries(1);
});

$(".arrow.right").click(function() {
  redrawCountries(-1);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  redrawCountries(1);
});
```

```css
.slider {
    position: absolute;
    top: 135px;
    left: 150px;
}
.slider > div {
    display:inline-block;
}
.slides {
    width:550px;
    height:53px;
    position:relative;
    font-size:70%;
}
.arrow {
    width: 16px;
    height: 15px;
    background: url(pictures/arrowsSprite.png) no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.arrow.left {
    background-position: -16px 0;
}
.left:hover {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
.arrow.right {
    background-position: -32px 0;
}
.right:hover {
    background-position: -48px 0
}
.slides > div span {
    min-width:50px;
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;
    top:25px;
    left:15px;
    text-align:center;
}
.slides > div {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#pos0, #pos1, #pos2, #pos3, #pos4, #pos5 {
    position: absolute;
    color: #0094d9;
}
#pos0 {
    top: 10px;
}
#pos1 {
    top: 2px;
    left: 90px;
}
#pos2 {
    left: 180px;
}
#pos3 {
    left: 280px;
}
#pos4 {
    top: 2px;
    left: 373px;
}
#pos5 {
    top: 10px;
    left: 463px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="arrow left"></div>
  <div class="slides">
    <div id="pos0"></div>
    <div id="pos1"></div>
    <div id="pos2"></div>
    <div id="pos3"></div>
    <div id="pos4"></div>
    <div id="pos5"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes,something like. But...It is difficult for me to understand redrawCountries function. Please, can you explain?

Comment: @JohnnyMnemonick Tried to explain it, if you need more explanation, don't hesitate to ask :)

Comment: Thank you for explaining! Can you also explain, how we get the value of "var i" in var countryIndex = Math.min(Math.max(i+offset, 0), countryHtml.length-1);

Comment: @JohnnyMnemonick Sorry, I don't understand, could you elborate?

Comment: Sorry for my bad question. You use `i` as parameter in `var moveElem = function (i)`. You wrote comments for code:                      _//Get the country (i+offset) and if it is lower than 0, make it zero, if it is higher than 5, make it 5_                                   `var countryIndex = Math.min(Math.max(i+offset, 0), countryHtml.length-1);` and _//Get the jQuery object of the current element_ for `var currElem = $("#pos"+i);` So I can't understand where from `i` gets the value...

Comment: @JohnnyMnemonick added further explanation: ``As offset indicates the country that is supposed to be at #pos0 at the end of the animation and passing in i requests that you animate #pos(i), the country that is supposed to end up in #pos(i) is (i+offset). So at #pos0 countryHtml[offset] is supposed to be used. at #pos1, countryHtml[1+offset] and so on.``

Comment: At first performed loop `if (dir === 1) {
    for (var i = 0;i < 5;i++) {
      moveElem(i);
    }
    $("#pos5").html(countryHtml[Math.min(Math.max(5+offset, 0), countryHtml.length-1)]);
    } else if (dir === -1) {    
    for (var i = 5;i > 0;i--) {
      moveElem(i);
    }` where from `i` gets it value and then passes as argument to the `moveElem` function. Am I right?

Comment: @JohnnyMnemonick so, what about the loop?

Comment: Oh, I just clarify, that `moveElem` function gets `i` value from loop and after that perfome. Do my thoughts rigt or mistake?

Comment: @JohnnyMnemonick CORRECT! =D

Comment: Thank You for helping! Sorry for my question.There're my first steps in JS and it so difficult to uderstand some momemts!

Comment: @JohnnyMnemonick No problem :) Everyone has to start somewhere XD